# Make parallel the crossing edges of opposite faces with three.js

Tags: three.js

As you can see in the example below, an edge crossing a face is never parallel to this of the opposite face. How can I get this done ?

```js
    "use strict";
    
    const  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.querySelector("canvas")});
    const  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 1, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 400;
    
    // Make a scene
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    // Make a cube.
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    
    // Make a material
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0x00FF00,
      wireframe: true,
    });
    
    // Create a mesh based on the geometry and material
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
    
    function resize() {
      var width = renderer.domElement.clientWidth;
      var height = renderer.domElement.clientHeight;
      if (renderer.domElement.width !== width || renderer.domElement.height !== height) {
        renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
        camera.aspect = width / height;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      }
    }
    
    function animate(time) {
      time *= 0.001;  // seconds
      resize();
      mesh.rotation.x = time * 0.5;
      mesh.rotation.y = time * 1;
    
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way the `BoxGeometry` algorithm works in Three.js. If you want to override the way in which the vertices are connected, you're going to have to manually build your `THREE.Geometry` [as outlined in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Geometry). The idea is as follows:

1. Init a `Geometry` object.
2. Add vertices to the geometry with `Vector3`
3. Define how the vertices will be connected with `Face3`

I got things started with 2 sides of the box in the demo below, but I'll leave the remaining 4 sides for you to figure out (it might help to draw it out with pen and paper to figure out how to connect the remaining `Face3`s).

```js
"use strict";
    
    const  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.querySelector("canvas")});
    const  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 1, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 400;
    
    // Make a scene
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    // 1. Start with empty geometry
    const geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    // 2. Add vertices to geometry
    geometry.vertices.push(
        // verts [0-3] are in in +z
        new THREE.Vector3( -100,  100, 100 ),
        new THREE.Vector3( -100, -100, 100 ),
        new THREE.Vector3(  100, -100, 100 ),
        new THREE.Vector3(  100,  100, 100 ),
        // verts [4-7] in -z
        new THREE.Vector3( -100,  100, -100 ),
        new THREE.Vector3( -100, -100, -100 ),
        new THREE.Vector3(  100, -100, -100 ),
        new THREE.Vector3(  100,  100, -100 ),
    );

    // 3. Connect vertices in desired order to make faces
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 2, 3 ) );
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 4, 5, 6 ) );
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 4, 6, 7 ) );
    
    // Make a material
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0x00FF00,
      wireframe: true,
    });
    
    // Create a mesh based on the geometry and material
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
    
    function resize() {
      var width = renderer.domElement.clientWidth;
      var height = renderer.domElement.clientHeight;
      if (renderer.domElement.width !== width || renderer.domElement.height !== height) {
        renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
        camera.aspect = width / height;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      }
    }
    
    function animate(time) {
      time *= 0.001;  // seconds
      resize();
      mesh.rotation.x = time * 0.5;
      mesh.rotation.y = time * 1;
    
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
```